# Retain the cursor position in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I have a QTextEdit control. It has a maximum limit (maximum number of characters it can hold). To implement this I have connected a slot to the textChanged() signal which removes the extra character when the total number of characters exceeds the allowed maximum.

With this I have some problems dealing with the cursor position. Can anyone tell me how to retain the cursor position in QTextEdit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your slot:

If num of chars exceeds maximum:

> Ask the QTextEdit for the Cursor:
>
> [QTextCursor QTextEdit::textCursor() const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#textCursor)
>
> Set the return value as your textEdit cursor (cause it returns a copy). From doc:
>
> Returns a copy of the QTextCursor that represents the currently visible cursor. Note that > changes on the returned cursor do not affect QTextEdit's cursor; use setTextCursor() to  > update the visible cursor.
>
> [void QTextEdit::setTextCursor(const QTextCursor & cursor)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#setTextCursor)
>
> Ask the cursor to delete last char
>
> [void QTextCursor::deletePreviousChar()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qtextcursor.html#deletePreviousChar)

(Edit)as code:

```
QTextCursor  cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
ui->textEdit->setTextCursor( cursor );
cursor.deletePreviousChar();
```

Comment: <pre><code>QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();                                                                  ui->textEdit->setTextCursor( cursor );</code></pre> what is the point of writing the above two line ? Its only getting the cursor position and setting it .

Comment: Documentation: `Returns a copy of the QTextCursor that represents the currently visible cursor. Note that changes on the returned cursor do not affect QTextEdit's cursor; use setTextCursor() to update the visible cursor.`

Answer (score 2):

If number exceeds the limit or wrong character is typed I'm using:

```
ui->textEdit->textCursor().deletePreviousChar();
```